# Rails 4 doesn't detect application after capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm currently trying to deploy a Rails 4 app using Capistrano 3. All going smoothly but I've got an issue, yeah ! I can't run any rails commands in my app.

Here is my related capistrano plugins :

```
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-unicorn-nginx'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
gem 'capistrano-secrets-yml'
gem 'capistrano-rails-console'
```

So when I run a `cap production rails:console` it give me this output:

```
    [b2458a1e] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1 ] as user@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [b2458a1e] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1 ]
DEBUG [b2458a1e] Finished in 0.528 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [2d552562] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails console production as user@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [2d552562] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails console production )
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /home/rails_app/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/    frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]
```

Any idea ?

**update 13/03 - add deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.3.5'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:foo/my_app.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }.call
set :branch, 'master'

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.1'
```

Comment: Where does the `rails:console` task come from? I don't see it provided by any of the capistrano gems you listed.

Comment: Have your confirmed what rails environment is being invoked?  (Am looking at your `INFO [2d552562] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails console production as user@x.x.x.x` line).   Are you able to login to the server directly and invoke `rails c` using the `same bundle exec` command?

Comment: @MattBrictson it comes from this plugin (capistrano-rails-console) https://github.com/ydkn/capistrano-rails-console

Comment: Seems like you are executing `rails console` outside of your application root directory. Requires your deploy.rb (+ related config for deploy environment) to investigate problem.

Comment: @Awea For any case check that you are using latest version of these gems.

Comment: @rdnewman I'm able to login to my server but running the same command produce the same effect sadly

Comment: @maxd I've added my deploy.rb, I will check the version of these gems in a moment -)

Comment: Then it's probably not related to capistrano.  I'd try prepending `RAILS_ENV=production` to your `bundle exec` command and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are missing `bin/rails` in the deployed copy of your Rails app. Here's what I would do:

1. Make sure the contents of your `bin` directory are added, committed, and pushed to your git repository. This will include `bin/rails` and `bin/rake`.
2. *Remove* `bin` from Capistrano's `:linked_dirs` setting in your `deploy.rb`.
3. Re-deploy.