# running rails console in Capistrano deployed app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've deployed a Rails app to AWS using Capistrano, and now I'm trying to start Rails console, but can't. If I go into `home/user/app-name/current/` and try running `rails c` I just get instructions on how to use the rails command.

Alternatively, I need to run a command, specifically a Searchkick command `ClassName.reindex` is there a way I'm missing to do this without opening the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rails c` is probably failing due to the fact that you are missing `bin/rails` in your deployed app. See this answer for a fix: [Rails 4 doesn't detect application after capistrano deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039927/rails-4-doesnt-detect-application-after-capistrano-deployment/29043442#29043442)

Once you get `bin/rails` working, you can run a command without using the console like this:

```
bundle exec rails runner ClassName.reindex
```

The `runner` Rails command loads your app and evaluates whatever Ruby code you supply.

Depending on how you've done your deployment, you may need to explicitly specify the environment, like this:

```
bundle exec rails runner -e production ClassName.reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these and let m,e know if you find them to be helpful.

https://github.com/ydkn/capistrano-rails-console

https://gist.github.com/benedikt/1115513